# Perl Mojolicious - How to make it handle multiple connections at once?

Tags: perl, cgi, websocket, mojolicious

I setup a quick Mojolicious server like this:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    sleep 5; #sleep here, I'm testing multiple connections at once

    $self->render_text('Hello World!');
};

app->start;
```

I then start it with: `perl Mojolicious.pl daemon --listen=https://127.0.0.1:3000`

Problem is, if I run this command concurrently:

`time curl https://127.0.0.1:3000/ -k`

It seems to only use 1 thread for requests, because if I make multiple requests at once, they can take much longer than 5 seconds.  It's as if they are all queued up.

Am I missing something here?  I'm wanting to use Mojolicous, but only if it can handle more than one client at a time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mojo `daemon` is a standalone HTTP server meant for development use, not production, and it only runs a single thread. For production you would want to either use the `fastcgi` option and a FastCGI-supporting webserver, or install a nice [PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PSGI)-compatible server like [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Starman) or [Starlet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Starlet) or [Plack::Handler::FCGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Plack%3a%3aHandler%3a%3aFCGI) or [Fastpass](http://github.com/miyagawa/fastpass) and then do

```
plackup -s Starman --port 3000 Mojolicious.pl
```

Comment: So if I set this up to run in Apache, for example.  It wouldn't have the issue at all?  I just noticed putting a call to `fork`, makes it work running under daemon, however.

Comment: Additional question, if this is setup for FastCGI, will it run a new process for each request?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Reading The Fine Manual of [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/). The Guides are very important. Specifically the sections regarding  [Hypnotoad](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Hypnotoad) - the built-in pre-forking webserver.

Answer (score 2):

```
use AnyEvent;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

my @stack = ();

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->render_later;
    push @stack, AnyEvent->timer ( after => 5, cb => sub {
        $self->render_text('Hello World!');
    });
};

app->start;
```

Answer (score 0):

The painless way to achieve multiple connections at once is to replace "daemon" for "prefork" (it may even works better than hypnotoad):

From:

```
app->start('daemon', '-l', 'http://*:8000');
```

To:

```
app->start('prefork', '-l', 'http://*:8000');
```

You can test it yourself with:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -wl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    for(my $wait = 10; $wait > 0; $wait--) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    $self->render(text => "OK");
};

# Uncomment to test hypnotoad. execute: hypnotoad ./this_script.pl
#app->config(hypnotoad => {listen => ['http://*:8000']});
#app->start;

# Test Daemon: (Uncomment next line)
#app->start('daemon', '-l', 'http://*:8000');

# Test Prefork: (Uncomment next line)
app->start('prefork', '-l', 'http://*:8000');
```

This is the benchmark:

```
$ ab -n 10 -c 10 -s 120 http://localhost:8000/ :
```

**Results:**

```
(totals)         min  mean[+/-sd] median   max       total time
daemon:         11008 92020 28464.5 101021  101022   101.022 seconds
hypnotoad:      10017 31525 18811.0 49030   49033    49.036 seconds
prefork:        20018 24020 5165.0  20020   30022    30.029 seconds
```

Ideally it would be that the total time would be close to 10 seconds... but I haven't find a way to improve those times (yet).